# Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js

I am using passport to authenticate users, I wrote the code below :
app.ts:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
})


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect:'/',
        failureRedirect:'/hhhhh',
        failureFlash: true
    })
)
const port = 4000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`go to http://localhost:${port}`);
    
})
```

and localStrategy.ts:

```
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";
passport.use(new Strategy(
    function(username: string, password: string, done){
        let user = users.find(u=>username === u.name);
        console.log(user);
        
        if (!user){
            return done(null, false, {message:'incorrect username'});
        }
        if(! (password == user.pw)){
            return done(null, false, {message:'incorrect password'})
        }
        return done(null, user)
    }
))
```

I get the error:
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local".

I found in answer that I should add like line of code after initializing passport:

```
require('./path/to/passport/config/file')(passport);
```

but I don't know how to write it in typescript, any help please

Answer (score 0):

Change `import { Strategy } from "passport-local";` to `import { LocalStrategy } from "passport-local`, as explained in the passport-local docs here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/